# Bulk image insert from multiple folders wiith images in folder wont work

Tags: php, mysql, bulkinsert, directory, bulk

hi Guys my bulk image insert script for mysql isnt working.i cant figure out why.
I have the upload Script in root directory and the images in a folder called img in this folder a folders named by category with images in it so insert into mysql.but he says me everytime "There were no matching files to insert into the database." dont know why paths should be okay i think.

Here is the script guys

```
$connect = mysql_connect($server,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect);




$dirs = array_filter(glob('img/*'), 'is_dir');
foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    $path  = "img/" . $dir . "/";
    $files = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_filter(glob("{$path}*.*"), 'is_file'));

    if (empty($files)) {
        echo "There were no matching files to insert into the database.";
    } else {
        $insertValues = array();
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $data           = getimagesize($file);
            $width          = $data[0];
            $height         = $data[1];
            $insertValues[] = "('Titel', {$dir}, '{$file}', '$width', '$height')";
        }
        $query = "INSERT INTO `gbpics` (`gbpictitel`, `gbpiccat`, `gbpicurl`, `gbpicwidth`, `gbpicheight`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $insertValues);
        if (!mysql_query($query)) {
            echo "There was a problem inserting the data.";
            trigger_error("Query failed: $query<br />Error: " . mysql_error());
        } else {
            echo "The data was inserted successfully.";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried a relative path? ```$path  = "./img/" . $dir . "/";```

Comment: @SloanThrasher yes tried it out not working

Comment: @SloanThrasher any other idea?

Comment: @SloanThrasher he says he has no files to insert.so i think he cant find the category folder.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $path;` after you first build it, see what values your getting.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
$path  = "img/" . $dir . "/";
```

is duplicating the img/ part.
Probably should be

```
$path  = $dir . "/";
```

Comment: Would always make it easier to get more than 'not working', but also noticed missing quotes around dir bit from `$insertValues[] = "('Titel', '{$dir}', '{$file}', '$width', '$height')";`